# Get label of <p:selectOneMenu> when using <f:selectItems> on Map

Tags: jsf, primefaces, label, selectonemenu

I am trying to get the label of `<p:selectOneMenu>` when using `<f:selectItems>` on a `Map`.

View:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{formBean.userRegion}" style="width:125px">
    <f:selectItems value="#{formBean.region.regions}"></f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Bean:

```
@Inject
private Region region; //where region.getRegions() is LinkedHashMap   

public void regionChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {

//it prints map element value but I need element name
            System.out.println("userRegion= " + userRegion);

        //...

    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggests that the model is broken. You should instead of a `Map<K, V>` have a `List<Region>` where the `Region` is an entity having `K` and `V` properties (and rename that backing bean currently having the class name `Region`).

Otherwise, just loop through the map to get the key by value.

E.g.

```
public static <K, V> K getKey(Map<K, V> map, V value) {
    for (Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(value)) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Which you then use as

```
String key = getKey(region.getRegions(), userRegion);
```

But, again, your model is broken. Better fix the model straight away instead of introducing ugly workarounds.